# PostgreSQL pg_dump v10 different size to v12

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have exported a schema from my PostgreSQL database (v10.6) and it is 634Mb using the following command:

```
pg_dump -Fc -n schema -v -O -U username -p 5432 -h host -d database > export.dump.gz
```

Using the exact same export command from v12 is 1.3Gb. I have read the pg_dump docs for v12 and v10 and there doesn't seem to have been a change in compression but checked and used the following command with the extra compression switch Z and the default value of 6.

```
pg_dump -Fc -n schema -v -O -U username -p 5432 -h host -d database -Z 6 > export.dump.gz
```

And this made no difference.

Does anyone know if the pg_dump was changed for v12?

Comment: I'm assuming you're certain that the two databases contain exactly the same records... Have you compared the size of the output with `-Fp`? I believe this writes records in the same format as `-Fc`, so it should tell you if the compression ratio is the differentiating factor.

Comment: So using the-Fp created a 4.6Gb file which is the same size as using -Fc with -Z 0. The data is identically. I used the 634Mb pg_dump file created from 10 and restored it into my v12 and then am trying to now export it and noticed the difference.

Comment: But is the `-Fp` (or `-Fc -Z 0`) dump from v12 bigger than the equivalent dump from v10? This should tell us whether the difference is in the compression algorithm or in the output format.

Comment: so using -Fp on v10 gives a 2.3Gb file

Comment: Ok, `-Fp` is a plain-text dump, so a simple `diff` of the two files should give you an idea of where the extra data is coming from

Comment: running an fc.exe file1.txt file.txt > diff.txt only outputs 26Kb of difference. Mainly where is says things like -- Dumped from database version 10.6, -- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.6 and the newer v12 says -- Dumped from database version 12.1 -- Dumped by pg_dump version 12.1. Very puzzling